# Microsoft Outlook "auto-dismissing" appointments - Office365

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2013, office365

I have 3 users that all of sudden started to experience their reminders "auto-dismissing" in Microsoft Outlook 2010/2013. The reminders window will pop up, but within 30 seconds the reminder window vanishes.  If you check the appointment, the reminder has been set to NONE. Reminders work properly in Outlook Web Access. I have tried the list below.  I am looking for more things to try.  Any help would be appreciated.

- outlook.exe /cleanreminders
- outlook.exe /resetfolders
- Outlook repair OST
- Outlook with all add-ins disabled
- Outlook in safemode
- Outlook with AV disabled
- New Outlook Profile
- New Windows Profile
- Upgrade Outlook 2010 to 2013
- NEW COMPUTER, fresh install of everything
- powershell - Set-Mailbox -Identity user@emailaddress.com -CalendarRepairDisabled $true

Anybody have more things for me to try?
My next step is to recreate the mailbox from scratch.
But 15GB over 3mbs is going to take days...

Help!
Thanks

Comment: Are there any macro's setup in these users' Outlook? Any extensions/plug-ins being used?  If you start Outlook in Safe mode (ie: `outlook.exe /safe`) does it behave the same way?  If you restart Windows in Safe Mode with Networking (but start Outlook normally) does it behave the same way?

Comment: What version of Exchange are you running? I say rebuild the profile and see if the issue goes away.

Comment: @Techie007, I had no luck with outlook safe mode, but I never tried Windows Safe Mode with Networking.  I will give that a shot!

Comment: @sunk818, Office365.  Thanks for the suggestion, but a new Outlook and Windows profile was already attempted.  I also gave the user a brand new computer!  ha!  Thanks!

Comment: You should try resetting their password. I'm going to guess that perhaps there is another device or service that has the password and may be dismissing the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

There was a second person (management) that also had these mailboxes in their Outlook 2010.  They had notifications disabled in their OUTLOOK SETTINGS.  They NEVER dismissed the appointments, they just had notifications disabled as a whole.  In my opinion this looks seems like a bug.  It appears that disabling notifications in Outlook 2010 auto-dismisses them.